# Contact Form not working !

Tags: contact

I have added a new Contact Us page but it's not working and says

> **E-mail has not been setup properly. Please add your contact e-mail!**

Please help... From where do I can configure it properly?
Here is the link **http://designstutorial.com/?page_id=93**

Comment: You're using a WooThemes premium theme - each theme comes with pretty good documentation - just log into the members area and you'll have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your WP admin section, and under Apperance, there should be a Theme Options section, see if there is a place to set the email there.

If not, see if the developer has provided some documentation.